# how to Implementation of intersection, difference and union with List<HashMap<String, Object>> in java

Tags: java, spring

I want to get intersection and difference between List<HashMap<String, Object>>
but below code just show true or false.

I want to get difference like [{prodCode=KR7279570006, accountNum=20101834049, orgCode=C1AACQ0000}]

I want to get intersection like [{prodCode=KR7020150009, accountNum=20402786856, orgCode=C1AACQ0000},
{prodCode=KR7020150009, accountNum=20101834049, orgCode=C1AACQ0000}]

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>>  stockListInDb = 
[{prodCode=KR7020150009, accountNum=20402786856, orgCode=C1AACQ0000}, 
{prodCode=KR7020150009, accountNum=20101834049, orgCode=C1AACQ0000}]
    
List<HashMap<String, Object>> presentedStockList = 
[{prodCode=KR7020150009, accountNum=20402786856, orgCode=C1AACQ0000}, 
{prodCode=KR7020150009, accountNum=20101834049, orgCode=C1AACQ0000}, 
{prodCode=KR7279570006, accountNum=20101834049, orgCode=C1AACQ0000}]
    
System.out.println("새로운 주식은 " + presentedStockList.removeAll(stockListInDb) );
System.out.println("홀딩한 주식은 " + stockListInDb.retainAll(presentedStockList));

새로운 주식은 true
홀딩한 주식은 true
```

Comment: Have you considered modeling your objects as actual types instead of `Map<String, Object>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also tried retainAll, but it's not working instead of using this use:
If you want the intersection of List1 and List 2
it will remove all elements from the list1 that are present in list 2. if you want the differencece just replace the List1 to list2 and vice versa.

```
List1.stream().filter(List2::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: thank you it works!
but, the difference is not working. if i replace list1 to list2, it show intersection.

Comment: try this:    presentedStockList.removeAll(stockListInDb)

Comment: then System.out.println("새로운 주식은 " + presentedStockList );

Comment: first remove the print the list

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set<String> result = stockListInDb.stream()
  .distinct()
  .filter(presentedStockList::contains)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

result will show the intersection of both lists

Comment: thank you!! it works.
do you know how to get difference?

Comment: I know it is already answered. However, for that you can use the same removeAll function for this. As at first it was giving you the boolean value that it is done that is the reason it is returning true at first.
However, after the statement 
 presentedStockList.removeAll(stockListInDb)
is executed . The presentedStockLIst will only contain the unique items and  you can check this by printing the presentedStockList